# Female writer meets a man, who's actually dead, in a lighthouse

Tags: identify-this-movie

I remember a film about a Female writer. Something bad happens to her and she moves, with the help of her friend, to a remote place near a beach and a Lighthouse. Story progress and she starts writing a novel but struggles, then she goes near the lighthouse and meets a man who works there. They meet very regularly. But suddenly something happens and after struggle she finds out that the man she met at lighthouse has been dead a long time. I didn't watch its ending but it shows the struggle of that lady to know if that man is really dead before meeting her or any other conspiracy is running. It doesn't looks like a horror film but a suspense thriller for sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it [Half Light](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0412798/)?

Extract from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_Light):

> In an effort to finish her novel and find some emotional peace, Rachel moves away to a remote cottage on the Scottish coast. [...]
>
> Troubled by the possibility that her son has returned from the grave, Rachel shares her troubles with a young and handsome lighthouse keeper named Angus (Matheson) and the two spark a romance that suddenly goes awry when she learns that Angus died seven years ago by committing suicide after murdering his wife and her lover in the lighthouse. [...]